# Xcode 8.2.1 compatibility

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a Mac Os Sierra 10.12.2 and I have Xcode 8.2.1 installed. I am totally new in the world of IOS application development and I have two fundamental questions.

1. What would be the most updated version of Xcode that my Mac would
       support?
2. If it is the one I have installed, can I develop
       applications for the most modern versions of IOS?

Comment: 8.2.1..?? Please update your Xcode from App Store.

Comment: You need Xcode 11.0 or later to properly support iOS 13. This requires macOS 10.14.4 or later. So it's a matter of what hardware you have and whether it supports that version of macOS or not.

Comment: It doesn't let me update the xcode because my Mac is 10.12.2.  In case I can't get a more updated Mac and develop my application in Xcore 8, could my application run on an Iphone 10 (for example) or not?

Comment: Yes, old apps can run on newer devices, maybe. Try it and see. But Apple will not let you submit an app to the App Store with such an old version of Xcode. But for writing your own app and for putting it on your own phone, it can work. Keep in mind that a lot has changed since Xcode 8. The skills you learn are going to be very out-of-date.